# Google Maps Marker anchor on far zoom levels

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, anchor, marker

I'm creating markers with the google maps api. The anchor of the marker is very precise for close zoom levels:

[image: marker at right place]

As you can see, the marker points on the end of the blue polyline.

If I zoom out, I get this:

[image: marker a bit off]

As you can see here, the marker suddenly points on the yellow part of the polyline - which is totally wrong.

I get the same problem with custom icons for the markers.

I guess the problem is somewhere in the way I draw my polyline.
In this example the blue part of the line is drawn first and then the yellow part. So I guess google maps 'decides' that yellow overlays blue. Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just figured it out on my own.

You can set a zIndex for polyline parts.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#PolylineOptions

Solution:
For every polyline I create I check the color - if the color is 'yellow' I set the zIndex 1, if the color is blue, the zIndex is set to 100. Problem solved =)